# Specifying file path in java causes FileNotFoundException

Tags: java

This piece of code throws a FileNotFoundException, i'm sure the file exists in my working directory, am i doing something wrong?

```
 private void generateInvoiceNumber(){ //uses reads previous invoice number and increments it.
        try {
                File invoiceFile = new File("./Invoices/invoiceFile.txt");
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(invoiceFile,false);
                Scanner getter = new Scanner(invoiceFile);

                this.invoiceNumber = getter.nextInt();
                writer.write(++invoiceNumber);
                writer.close();
                getter.nextInt();
                getter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you start the file with ./? Java uses the execution folder unless a drive is specified in the path

Comment: well earlier i was trying to create the file in the previous directory using the ".." notation so i thought it wouldnt make a difference. 
Also i tried removing it and it didnt work as well.

Answer (score 1):

My tip:
Print (in your code) the current path location.
Then you can use this path in order to find the exact path you should use in order to access your file.

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system you are using?
It’s better to use paths when you are constructing a path to your file like

```
File file = Paths.get (".","Invoices", "invoice.txt").toFile();
```

- corrected `"` symbols and default root `"."` which is your folder where app started.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put more concrete absolute path:

```
File invoiceFile = Paths.get ("C:","Invoices", "invoiceFile.txt").toFile();
```

or if you trying to get from current path:

```
File invoiceFile = Paths.get (".","Invoices", "invoiceFile.txt").toFile();
```

And you can check your . path:

```
 System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());
```